# WSO2 Payload factory mediator shows Illegal character<D>

Tags: json, apache, wso2, axiom, wso2-esb

I have a payload factory mediator in my proxy service, which looks like below.

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{
   "EntityTypeCode":"asx",
   "SchoolId":$1,
   "Format":"json",
   "InputData":{
      "Accounts":{
         "Account":[
            {
               "UserName":$2,
               "StudentID":$3,
               "FirstName":$4,
               "LastName":$5,
               "Email":$6,
               "DOB":$7,
               "SSN":$8,
               "Password":$9,
               "GenderCode":$10,
               "Address1":$11,
               "City":$12,
               "State":$13,
               "ZipCode":$14
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('SchoolId')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml"
                    expression="$body/*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='Payload']/*[local-name()='ID'][*[local-name()='Type']='abc']/*[local-name()='Value']/text()"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml"
                    expression="$body/*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='Payload']/*[local-name()='ID'][*[local-name()='Type']='abc']/*[local-name()='Value']/text()"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('first_name')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('last_name')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('email_address')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('birth_date')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml"
                    expression="$body/*[local-name()='Object']/*[local-name()='Payload']/*[local-name()='ID'][*[local-name()='Type']='abc']/*[local-name()='Value']/text()"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('birth_date')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('sex')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('street_line1')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('city')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('stat_code')"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('zip')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
```

On executing the above payload factory mediator, I am getting the below error.

> ERROR - SequenceMediator javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Illegal
>   character:  org.apache.axiom.om.OMException:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Illegal character: 
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.buildNext(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:880)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:343)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:554)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:686)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:555)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:125)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serialize(OMSerializableImpl.java:113)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:988)
>           at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.stringValueOf(SynapseXPath.java:321)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorProperty.getEvaluatedExpression(MediatorProperty.java:138)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.setCustomProperties(LogMediator.java:223)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getSimpleLogMessage(LogMediator.java:168)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:134)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:101)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:213)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Illegal character: 
>           at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:449)
>           at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:456)
>           at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
>           ... 31 more

What could be the reason? Where am I going wrong?

Please help to overcome the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments your inserted via $1,$2 and so on - is it strings or numbers? If strings - put them into "", like:

```
"UserName":"$2",
"StudentID":$3,
"FirstName":"$4",
```